# Filtering key-value options

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value, options

I want to define a new environment whose implementation depends on another environment. The first environment should accept a list of key-value options. Some of these options are for use only on this first environment. All options not known to the first environment are to be passed to the other environment.

Is there any package for dealing with options filtering in LaTeX?

Comment: You've tagged [tag:pgfkeys] but the question is open for all keyval packages: should we prefer `pgfkeys`?

Comment: Are these environments used in a nested sense, or completely separate, or perhaps both?

Comment: `pgfkeys` has `/.try` handler.

Comment: @JosephWright I have started programming this environment using `pfgkeys`, as it seems to be very powerful, but if other keyval package offers some useful feature to accomplish what I need, than I can try it.

Comment: @Werner, I think I can say the environments will be nested. The environment will be used to typeset code listings. The contents of the environment will be typeset with the help of pygments, which will use some macros to add style to the listing. The result will be the content of another environment like `mdframed`, `tcolorbox`, `boite`, `framed`, `Verbatim`, which would allow drawing a frame around the listing, setting the background, or producing other effects.

Answer (score 1):

There are different key=value packages for which you can do the following (in essence, every key=value package that allows you to define unknown-handlers yourself). I'll show an example using `expkv` of this approach (disclaimer: I'm `expkv`'s author).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{myenv}
  {
     store blubb = \myenvBlubb
    ,store foo   = \myenvFoo
    ,store bar   = \myenvBar
    % this implements the filtering, instead of throwing errors for unknown keys
    % we store them in a list
    ,protected unknown noval =
      \edef\myenvUnknown{\unexpanded\expandafter{\myenvUnknown,#1}}
    ,protected unknown code =
      \edef\myenvUnknown{\unexpanded\expandafter{\myenvUnknown,#1= {#2}}}
    % some auxiliary keys to restore the unknown list to empty
    ,protected noval clear-unknowns = \let\myenvUnknown\empty
    % initialise the empty unknown-list
    ,initial clear-unknowns
  }

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {%
    \ekvset{myenv}{#1}%
    \expanded{\unexpanded{\begin{tcolorbox}}\expandafter}%
      \expandafter[\myenvUnknown]%
  }
  {%
      \tcblower
      blubb: \myenvBlubb\\
      foo: \myenvFoo\\
      bar: \myenvBar\\
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}{colback=blue!30!white,bar=EC,title=example, foo=Foobar}
  This is an example.
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

---

Another approach can be to use a key=value implementation that supports setting only known keys and storing the unknown keys in a list by using some special syntax (this doesn't require you to code the list-building yourself as done above). One such implementation is `l3keys` with its `\keys_set_known:nnN`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__myenv_unknown_tl
\keys_define:nn { myenv }
  {
     blubb .tl_set:N = \l__myenv_blubb_tl
    ,foo   .tl_set:N = \l__myenv_foo_tl
    ,bar   .tl_set:N = \l__myenv_bar_tl
  }
\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {%
    \keys_set_known:nnN { myenv } {#1} \l__myenv_unknown_tl
    \exp_last_unbraced:NnNo \begin { tcolorbox } [ \l__myenv_unknown_tl ]
  }
  {%
      \tcblower
      blubb:~ \l__myenv_blubb_tl\\
      foo:~ \l__myenv_foo_tl\\
      bar:~ \l__myenv_bar_tl\\
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}{colback=blue!30!white,bar=EC,title=example, foo=Foobar}
  This is an example.
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

---

Both code blocks give identical results:

[image]